# Jquery check asp:radiobuttonlist if selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have jquery code and I have a small problem with it. I am doing a Poll-Selecton system and everything works fine. But today I decided to put 2 lines of code to check if the user selected one of the radio buttons. I am using ASP:RadioButtonlist.

The problem is now, when user click submit button without selecting a radio button, it displays the ALERT() box. That s perfect. After that, user select one of the radio button and then clicks the submit button, but submit button doesnt get triggered. How can I solve this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=btn_poll_submit.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {

                 // CHECKS IF RADIOBUTTON SELECTED
                 //********************************
                if ($('#<%=rbl_poll.ClientID %> input:checked').val() == undefined) {
                    alert("PLEASE MAKE SELECTION");
                }
                else{

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ViewPost.aspx/insert_post_poll_selections",
                        data: "{'ProfessionalId':'1','choice_id':'" + $('#<%=rbl_poll.ClientID %> input:checked').val() + "','PostId':'<%=Session["SessionPostId"].ToString() %>','UserId':'<%=Session["SessionUserId"].ToString() %>'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#<%=pnl_poll_result.ClientID %>').html(data.d);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

THANK YOU

Comment: I think xhr url might be wrong. Could you please test the same using httpfox add on in firefox.

Comment: You don't cancel the click/submit event when the poll is invalid, thus submitting invalid data. Add `return false;` after your `alert`.

Comment: Show your markup where `rbl_poll` and  asp:radiobuttonlist is defined.

Comment: Thank you very much. you solved the problem, JERONE.